# Automate univariate and multivariable logistic models, return formatted results in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, tidyverse, gtsummary

I need to run several univariate and multivariable logistic regression models from the same dataset. I thus need to loop this to avoid duplicating the same code.

I hope to be able to clearly label my output tables, with a title so I can tell apart the different models within an RMarkdown PDF document e.g. "Univariate regression: Outcome = **out1**", the variable part being the "*out1*" (*out1 - out3*), similarly for multivariable models something like "Mutivariable regression: Outcome = **out1**" for *out1 - out*

I am using the gtsummary package so I can get nicely formatted results together with the accompanying footnotes.

I have tried the following but I have not succeeded. Shall appreciate any assistance.

```
# Libraries
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)

# Data as well as a few artificial variables
data("iris")
my_iris <- as.data.frame(iris)

my_iris$out1 <- sample(c(0,1), 150, replace = TRUE)
my_iris$out2 <- sample(c(0,1), 150, replace = TRUE)
my_iris$out3 <- sample(c(0,1), 150, replace = TRUE)

my_iris$x1 <- sample(c(1:12), 150, replace = TRUE)
my_iris$x2 <- sample(c(50:100), 150, replace = TRUE)
my_iris$x3 <- sample(c(18:100), 150, replace = TRUE)


# This is the list of outcome variables I need to run univariate and multivariable logistic regressions for.
outcome <- c("out1", "out2", "out3")

# Univariate logistic models
for (out in seq_along(outcome)) {
my_iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(outcome[out], Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species) %>% 
  tbl_uvregression(method = glm,
                   y = outcome[out],
                   method.args = list(family = binomial),
                   exponentiate = TRUE) %>%
  bold_labels() 
}


# Multivariable logistic models
for (out in seq_along(outcome)) {
  tbl_regression(glm(outcome[out] ~ Species + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, my_iris, family = binomial), exponentiate = TRUE)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put them into functions and then use any of the apply functions to loop it.

```
uni_tbl_model <- function(my_iris, outcome) {
  model <- glm(my_iris[,outcome] ~ Sepal.Length, my_iris, family = binomial)
  tbl <- tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE)
  tbl <- tbl %>% modify_caption(paste("Univariate Regression Model with", outcome, "as Outcome", sep = " "))
  print(tbl)
}

multi_tbl_model <- function(my_iris, outcome) {
  model <- glm(my_iris[,outcome] ~ Species + Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width, my_iris, family = binomial)
  tbl <- tbl_regression(model, exponentiate = TRUE)
  tbl <- tbl %>% modify_caption(paste("Multivariable Regression Model with", outcome, "as Outcome", sep = " "))
  print(tbl)
}

sapply(outcomes, function(outcome) uni_tbl_model(my_iris, outcome))
sapply(outcomes, function(outcome) multi_tbl_model(my_iris, outcome))
```

Comment: thanks. It nicely solves the multivariable part. But how can I adapt this to work with univariate regression? tbl_uvregression function requires only the outcome variable to be specified and it includes all the dataframe variables in the model as predictors. This is not what I want as I want to select some predictor variables to be included and certainly not the other outcome variables. How do I tackle this please?

Comment: You don't need to use the `tbl_uvregression` function, just edit the regression equation in the model to be univariate. I edited my earlier answer to show.

Answer (score 1):

Following your question...

*This is the list of outcome variables I need to run univariate and multivariable logistic regressions for.*

```
outcome <- c("out1", "out2", "out3")
```

*This is my suggestion*

With these vectors you can control which variables to include in uni and multivariate models.

```
    pred.uni<-c('Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species')
    pred.multi<-c('Sepal.Width','Species')
```

## Models

### Univariate logistic models

```
     mod.uni.list<-list()
                for (out in seq_along(outcome)) {
                  mod.uni.list[[out]] <- my_iris %>%
                    # dplyr::select(outcome[out], Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, Species) %>%
                    tbl_uvregression(
                      method = glm,
                      y = outcome[out],
                      method.args = list(family = binomial),
                      exponentiate = TRUE,
                      include = all_of(pred.uni)
                    ) %>% # include allows to choose predictor variables. Default is everything.
                    bold_labels()
                  
                }
     names(mod.uni.list)<-outcome #This is not necessary but it could be usefull to call models later.
```

### Multivariable logistic models

```
 

  mod.multi.list <- list()
      for (out in seq_along(outcome)) {
        mod.multi.list[[out]] <-
          tbl_regression(glm(eval(parse(
            text = paste0(outcome[out], '~', paste(pred.multi, collapse = '+'))
          )), my_iris, family = binomial), exponentiate = TRUE)
          }
```

### Merging both tables and adding title with tab_header and some format with tab_style.

```
 

     mod.combo.list<-list()
      for (out in seq_along(outcome)) {
        mod.combo.list[[out]] <-
          tbl_merge(
            list(mod.uni.list[[out]], mod.multi.list[[out]]),
            tab_spanner = c('Univariate', 'Multivariate')
          ) %>%
          # All the styling options go after the conversion of merged table into a gt table.
          as_gt() %>% # Conversion to gt table before customizing table.
          gt::tab_style(
            style = list(# cell_fill(color = 'orange'),
              cell_text(weight = 'bold')),
            locations = cells_body(columns = c(`p.value_1`),
                                   rows = `p.value_1` < 0.1)
          ) %>%
          gt::tab_style(
            style = list(# cell_fill(color = 'orange'),
              cell_text(weight = 'bold')),
            locations = cells_body(columns = c(`p.value_2`),
                                   rows = `p.value_2` < 0.1)
          ) %>%
          gt::tab_header(title = md("IRIS")
                         , subtitle = md(
                           paste0(
                             "Univariate and multivariate logistic regression 
    models on the outcome ",
                             outcome[out]
                           )
                         )) %>%
          gt::opt_align_table_header(align = c("left"))
        
      }
      names(mod.combo.list)<-outcome #This is not necessary but it could be useful to call models later.
```

Now you can call them all.

```
    mod.combo.list$out1
    mod.combo.list$out2
    mod.combo.list$out3
```

```
         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
2  bench.mult            5   36.44    1.000     35.28     0.95
3 bench.super            5   37.42    1.027     36.74     0.53
1   bench.uni            5   96.30    2.643     93.24     2.41
```

As you can see in the rbenchmark output, the bottleneck is in tbl_univariate. Once I read that this happens because the function runs one model for each variable and stacks them after each loop. Sure that Daniel D. Sjoberg has a better answer.

I guess this also depends on the hardware. This is the benchmark output (5 replicates) in my laptop (i7-8550U,1.8GHz,2-core,16GB RAM).